# How to add extra parameters in tracking URL in eloqua email?

Tags: c#, rest, eloqua

I am working on eloqua 10.

I have a scenario like this, suppose i am creating a an email in eloqua and which has a tracking link on the email template.

http://www.mytestsite.com/page.html?elqTrack=true

Now,I would like to pass the contacts email address to be appended to the above link loke this

http://www.mytestsite.com/page.html?elqTrack=true&email={emailaddress}

Is there any way to add a placeholder or query string to the above tracking url , so that it will dynamically loads with the email address of the users in the segment; while viewing the campaign by the end user ?

Got my point, so

When i see the email campaign the link will be

http://www.mytestsite.com/page.html?elqTrack=true&email=myemail@mydomain.com

and for some other users i will be

http://www.mytestsite.com/page.html?elqTrack=true&email=otheruser@theirdomain.com

Do eloqua support this kind of functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add eloqua email field merge:

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/page.html?elqTrack=true&email=<span class=eloquaemail>EmailAddress</span>
```

If you would like to track who clicked your links this is usually done by Blind form submit. You need to create a form within Eloqua and use this code in your anchor. 
Edit the information in brackets and delete the brackets too. This will submit a form without person knowing it. You can create extra fields in the eloqua form and append them to this query just by adding "&htmlFieldName=xxx". This is in case you want to capture more information.

```
<a href="http://s1234.t.eloqua.com/e/f2?elqFormName={ADD FORM NAME HERE}&elqSiteID={ADD ID - GetThisFromTheFormHTML}&emailAddress=<span class=eloquaemail>EmailAddress</span>">
```

In the form processing steps redirect to the desired url.

Answer (score 1):

Can Use like this 
[image]

above span tag was taken from field merge value

**Note :**

Original Field Merge tag :

[image]

Need to remove the double qoutes for class

[image]

and add this to URL.